# Vue Bus Event with Props Executes Only Once

Tags: vue.js, event-handling

I'm having difficulty finding why an event bus emits only once between two Vue components.

A button interaction is to open a child components' panel and then dynamically/lazyly loads a pair of chart components. Then, on the second execution, close the panel and destroy the dynamically loaded components. The functions cycle works but only once.

> **UPDATE:**
>
> After adding some UI components inside of the `<q-card>` directive, I discovered that `this.toggleChartPanel()` toggles on every interaction with the button event. It appears that the the props loads only on the FIRST-TIME the button is clicked.

*A code example with explanation would be greatly appreciated.*

**Component containing the `emit`:**

```html
<script>
import Store from '@store'
import BaseHrsBtn from './_base-hrs-btn'

export default {
  name: 'TotHrs',
  parent: 'LogSummaryWidget',

  components: {
    BaseHrsBtn,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      dynamicCharts: {
        dynamicChartA: 'test-line-chart',
        dynamicChartB: 'test-line-chart'
      }
    }
  },

  computed: {
    totHrs () {
      return Store.state.fetchLogSummary.data.total
    },
  },

  methods: {
    emitChartPanelToggle () {
      this.$bus.$emit('chart-panel-toggled', this.dynamicCharts)
      this.dynamicCharts = {}
    },
  },
}
</script>


<template>

  <base-hrs-btn
    class="col-6 col-md-4"
    :hours="totHrs"
    icon="clock"
    title="TOT"
    @click.native="emitChartPanelToggle"
  />

</template>
```

```html
<script>
export default {
  name  : 'ChartPanel',
  parent: 'LogSummaryWidget',

  components: {
    TestLineChart: () => import("./_charts/test-line-chart"),
  },

  data () {
    return {
      chartPanelOpen: false,
      dynamicChartA: '',
      dynamicChartB: '',
    }
  },

  created() {
    this.$bus.$on('chart-panel-toggled', ({ dynamicChartA, dynamicChartB}) => {
      this.toggleChartPanel()
      this.dynamicChartA = dynamicChartA
      this.dynamicChartB = dynamicChartB
    });
  },

  beforeDestroy() {
    this.$bus.$off('chart-panel-toggled');
  },

  methods: {
    toggleChartPanel () {
      this.chartPanelOpen = !this.chartPanelOpen
    }
  },
}
</script>


<template>

  <q-card
    v-show-slide="chartPanelOpen"
    class="q-mx-md"
  >
    <component :is="dynamicChartA"></component>
    <component :is="dynamicChartB"></component>

  </q-card>

</template>
```

Also, how can I insure that the `$bus.$on` fires asynchronously too?

Comment: Where is `this.$bus` defined?

Comment: As a plugin (a few other work just fine): `import VueBus from 'vue-bus';

export default ({ Vue }) => {
  Vue.use(VueBus);
};`

Comment: See update section in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally left this in:

`this.dynamicCharts = {}`

Removing it fixed it.